C input VS Code
I am going through the edx CS50 course for 2024, I am in the 1st week of C programming. The CS50 course has the user use the online CS50 program that includes the CS50.h module.
This allows me to use <cs50.h> which includes inputs for certain data types. I have been using int height = get_int("height"), in regular VS Code I am unable to utilize #include <CS50.h> for user input. How would I get user input in standard C?
I saw some post about scanf() and printf() for input and output but can someone explain these functions further?
I tried to include the CS50.h module but I get an error that VS Code doesn't recognize it. I want to get standard input and output in C.

Welcome! You can write your own version of get_int(), which might be based around fgets() and strtoll(). You could give added value too, by adding min and max acceptable values as function arguments.

"How would I get user input in standard C?" - Do you have a book on C or are they teaching C without a proper book that you can read?

In some ways it's good for CS50 to shelter its students from the difficulties of scanf(). It's a complex and tricky function to use, and it needs a mini-tutorial just on its own. Reckon on spending a few hours exploring it. Also the printf() family of functions is quite detailed. Those two functions have many similarities, and major differences too.

How to use the function scanf is explained in week 4 of CS50. However, using that function is generally not recommended. See these two links for further information: 1. A beginners' guide away from scanf() 2. What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?

Note that scanf() family is intended for formatted input, and if the input doesn't comply it's difficult to recover. It's a poor choice for user input, and much easier (from the view of program control) if you use fgets() and sscanf(). But you still need a good understanding of the scanf() function family. With some programs, maybe more than half the code is devoted to robust user input, disproportionate to the task at hand.

You might want to try asking how to use cs50.h with vscode in [cs50.se]

What is your environment? You once wrote cs50.h and CS50.h at another place. On Linux systems, these are completely different files and only cs50.h is the valid one. Did you install CS50 on your system? Where did you put the header and the C file? Maybe you need "cs50.h" instead of <cs50.h>

Nothing about using VS Code prevents you from using any third-party library.  It is just an code editor, not a tool chain.  You are asked Ng the wrong question.  It is probably important to you stick to the course material for a tutor graded course. https://github.com/cs50/libcs50

"How would I get user input in standard C?" A better C class would address that in the very first lesson, not keep you in the dark and treat you like a dummy. Yes the reason they do this is because the horrible stdio.h library is notoriously error-prone. But beginners need not worry about that, they aren't going to write bug-free production quality code when still learning the very basics. Learning how to use the details of stdio.h is mostly irrelevant knowledge, but beginners can still use the most basic parts of it for learning purposes.


in regular VS Code I am unable to utilize #include <CS50.h>.


How would I get user input in standard C (to replace get_int("height"))?

Search for sample source code or roll your own.
Much depends on error handling.
Let's say code exits on errors.

Send prompt.
Read a line of user input with fgets() into a string.
In general, avoid scanf() until you know why it is bad.
Convert the string into an int.
Perform testing all along the way.

#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_int(const char *prompt) {
  // Send prompt.
  if (prompt) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
  }
  fflush(stdout);

  // Read input.
  char buffer[100];  // Something at least 2x longer than ever expected.
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No input.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Parse input.
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long val = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 10);

  // Look for errors.
  if (buffer == endptr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Non-numeric input <%s>.\n", buffer);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE || val < INT_MIN || val > INT_MAX) {
    errno = ERANGE;  // Useful if code did not exit.
    fprintf(stderr, "Input out of int range <%s>.\n", buffer);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while (isspace(*((unsigned char* )endptr))) {
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr != '\0') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input has trailing non-white-space junk <%s>.\n", buffer);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // We made it!
  return (int) val;
}

To do:

Add code to handle lines 100 characters or longer.

Check output functions' return values.

Maybe handle non-decimal input or exponential input like 1e4.

Create other missing get_xxx() functions.


